# How can I replace the occurrence of a letter within a string with a number

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an input field where I can enter a text and I would like to replace the occurrence of Vowels with numbers.

eg - (A,E,I,O,U - 1,2,3,4,5) and add '**a**' to all the other consonants.

eg - The input field takes in 'Victor as an input and what is printed on the page is '`Va3cata4ra`'.

So far, I've been able to get the consonants to display an '**a**' at the end of it using template literals and passing the variable to a `setState`. However I'm having issues getting the Vowels to show their numerical values as explained above. I've tried `Switch` , `if else`, for some reason, none is working

```
export default class App extends Component {

state = {
    mytext: ''
}

onChangeHandler = (event) => {
        const newText = event.target.value;
        const splitText = newText.split('');
        let tempArr = []

        for (let onye in splitText) {
            else if (onye === 'e') {
                onye.replace(parseInt('2'))
            } else if (onye === 'i') {
                onye.replace(parseInt('3'))
            } else if (onye === 'o') {
                onye.replace(parseInt('4'))
            } else if (onye === 'u') {
                onye.replace(parseInt('5'))
            } else {
                return onye
            }

            //This got the consonants to display a after each one

            const raCon = `${splitText[onye]}a`
            tempArr.push(raCon)
        }

        this.setState({
            mytext: tempArr
        })
```

Expected result would have '**a**' at the end of each consonant and numerical values for every vowel corresponding with (A,E,I,O,U)- (1,2,3,4,5)

Comment: What's the added "a" for. Seems kind of silly xD

Comment: It's part of the assignment . Like the FizzBuzz Code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create an object where the object keys will be the vowel and set the value as required. Then use `split` to create an array of the characters of the input text. and use `reduce` to create the new string. In the reduce callback function check if the current character on iteration is key of the object. If so then retrieve the value and `concat` , else just concat current character &  `a` and return it

```js
let vowelCrypt = {
  a: 1,
  e: 2,
  i: 3,
  o: 4,
  u: 5
}

function cryptInput(input) {
  if (input.length > 0) {
    return input.split('').reduce(function(acc, curr) {
      if (vowelCrypt[curr]) {
        acc += vowelCrypt[curr];
      } else {
        acc += curr + 'a';
      }
      return acc;
    }, '')


  }
}

console.log(cryptInput('Victor'))
```

Answer (score 2):

You could take a replacement function and take a letter to replace and and object with replacement values.

```js
function replace(string) {
    return string.replace(/[aeiou]/gi, c => ({ a:1, e: 2, i: 3, o: 4, u: 5 }[c.toLowerCase()]));
}

console.log(replace('banana'));
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming your code looks something like this, we can just define a converter function to swap the vowels with numbers and add an "a" to each consonant.

```
class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    myText: ""
  };

  onChange = event => {
    this.setState({
      myText: event.target.value
    });
  };

  convertWord = word => {
    let vowels = ["a", "e", "i", "o", "u"];
    let letters = word.toLocaleLowerCase().split("");

    return letters.map(letter =>
      vowels.includes(letter) ? vowels.indexOf(letter) + 1 : letter + "a"
    );
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <input onChange={this.onChange} value={this.state.myText} />
        Converted Word: {this.convertWord(this.state.myText)}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Also see sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/priceless-mcnulty-xyhbr

Answer (score 0):

You can use reduce to solve this.

```js
const convertVowels = (str) => {
 const vowels = ['a','e','i','o','u'];
 return str.split('').reduce((newStr, char) => {
  if(vowels.includes(char)) {
   return newStr += (vowels.indexOf(char)+1)
  } else {
   return newStr += char+'a';
  }
 }, '');
}

console.log(convertVowels('Victor'))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to iterate the letters and replace.

```
const newText = event.target.value;
const wovels = ['A','E','I','O','U'];
let p = newText.split('').map(e => {   
    let idx = wovels.indexOf(e.toUpperCase());
    if(idx !== -1){
        return idx+1;
    } else {
        return e+'a';
    }
})
console.log(p.join(''));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a function like this:

```
function converter(str) {
  charArr = str.split('');
  charArr.forEach(function (c, i) {
    if (c === 'a') {
      charArr[i] = 1;
    } else if (c === 'e') {
      charArr[i] = 2;
    } else if (c === 'i') {
      charArr[i] = 3;
    } else if (c === 'o') {
      charArr[i] = 4;
    } else if (c === 'u') {
      charArr[i] = 5;
    } else {
      charArr[i] += 'a';
    }
  });
  return charArr.join('');
}
```